# Identify this show about an AI shipping company that won't stop

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

I recently saw a show (movie, episode, anthology episode) about a post apocalyptic AI that continued to produce and ship goods in large quantities even though people had no need for the products.

> The people eventually trick the AI into sending a customer service robot and manipulate her to get the AI to stop.

The story is similar to a [paperclip maximizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_convergence#Paperclip_maximizer).

Comment: This was an anthology episode of something cheap

Comment: I believe it was an episode of Dark Mirror but I can't look into that right now.

Comment: Related, not dupe; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76376/short-story-in-book-collection-about-war-machines-and-armies-out-of-control

Comment: It's neither “The Sorceror's Apprentice” nor “The Midas Plague”? :P

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is [Autofac](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt6902176/) from the anthology TV show *Electric Dreams*.

> Society and the world as we know it has collapsed. A massive, automatic factory operates according to the principles of consumerism; humans consume to be happy, and in order to consume continuously, they must be denied freedom of choice and free will. When a small band of rebels decide to shut down the factory, they discover they may actually be the perfect consumers after all.

Comment: I’m glad this answer is not at all pizzled.

Comment: Do you want milk? Obligatory [Philip K. Dick review](https://philipkdickreview.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/autofac/)